# Java How to test api gateway endpoints without deploying

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, mockito, api-gateway

I want to learn how to unit test API gateway endpoints, or just in general, before deploying the API.
For example, how could I test something like:

```
public class someController {

     private SomeService someService;

     @GET
     @Path("...")
     public String someMethod(){
        return someService.someMethod();
     }

}
```

someSerivce:

```
public class SomeService{
   public String someMethod(){
   //make http request to api gateway
   return json string
   }

}
```

How would I test "someService" class. I assume the "someController" class would just ensure "someMethod" is being called by making use of Mockito `verify(someService).someMethod();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mock of `SomeService`, inject it into `SomeController` (via constructor or setter).

Set up the mock behaviour with when/thenReturns. Eg:

```
when(someServiceMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("foo bar")
```

Call `SomeController.someMethod()` and check the result.

If you are Spring then you can take this further by using `WebMvcTest` with an `@Autowired MockMvc`

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
```

To call the actual path and http method, headers, etc.

```
mockMvc.perform(get("...").andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am reading your question correctly that you want to do a test call one of your service methods and see the response, and if you are using IntelliJ, you can potentially use this plugin [1] with your application to invoke the methods on your service class and see the result.

[1] https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18529-unlogged

Disclaimer: I am a contributor of that plugin.